# Upgrade to CiviCRM 5.65.2

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Upgrade from CiviCRM 5.60 to 5.65.2 with no annunciated errors or warnings, including db updates. I am using Drupal 7.98. Now getting this warnings in civi status:

Warning: Declaration of com_clickandpledge_payment_clickandpledge::doTransferCheckout(&$params, $component) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Payment::doTransferCheckout(&$params, $component = 'contribute') in require_once() (line 52 of /home/resoluter/public_html/t1/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php).

I have fixed this type of error before but this time, I am not able to find the offending declaration after extensive searching. How can I find the offender?
Thanks

Comment: Try a grep for `doTransferCheckout` on your server files.

Comment: Thanks yeah, had done that and had previously found and fixed similar issues with other old declarations of other old methods. No joy on this one yet. But good to hear you agree with process, I will try again.
Thank you!

Comment: Answered as I proceeded for now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a perennial problem with the Joomla upgrader: When it updates a plugin it doesn't clean up old files. So old obsolete files can linger instead of being deleted, causing errors.

I'm not sure if that's the exact cause of this problem, but I wanted to flag if to you as a general preventative measure: always delete a plugin's directory before upgrading the component, because Joomla won't do it for you.

Comment: We are not using any of the payment components at this time, so removal of the right old file is a possible good direction.
Prior to the CivicCRM file intalls and per instructions, I did file system and db backups then removed at this level:
$ pwd
/home/.../public_html/t1/sites/all/modules
$ rm -rf ./civicrm 
$ tar -xvf civicrm-5.65.2-drupal.tar.gz

The tar expansion did recreate my 
/home/.../public_html/t1/sites/all/modules/civicrm
along with all the new 5.65.2 files below.
Should I have removed any other old files?
Should I remove: ../civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you did the right thing with upgrading CiviCRM core. What about extensions? They should be in a separate directory, like your uploads folder.

Comment: Good suggestion. I did all recommended extension updates, which ran smoothly. Unfortunately the exact same warning still comes up on the CiviCRM system page at the top, but the rest of the status page shows extensions are current and the overall system status now shows us at 5.65.2. We are using this as a starting point to migrate from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9, both at CiviCRM 5.65.2. Our core app data is ok, i think i will ignore the warning and keep going then fix it under Drupal 9 with cleaner updates. If I am in left field, please point it out! Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I consider this "answered" as our Drupal 7 site is solid and doing what we need from it for now other than this warning message in the system status page. We are moving to Drupal 9 ASAP, hopefully in the next. 2 weeks as which time such clean ups, clean outs, extension upgrades will be better controlled via the composer controlled upgrade process. 
Thank you!